# Jenkins fails to pick a valid build number

Tags: jenkins

I have an "official" Jenkins running on ServerA, and a copy (copy of the .jenkins folder) that runs on ServerB and is slated to become the new official Jenkins, so we are testing it. Both installations are active.

I find today that, when I try to start a build on the new server, it complains that the build number 704 already  exists, and indeed it does. So I wonder why it didn't pick a fresh number. The number it picks (and fails) is a number that was indeed used on this new server nine days ago. That build ran to  success.

As a test, I deleted build 704, and retried it. It then picked 705 as a number, and is now running. However a previous and conflicting build may be significant and not to be deleted, so this is not really a workaround....

Thanks for any clues!

Comment: Where is the interaction between ServerA and ServerB? Does the issue here stem from a desire to persist the build logs (and subsequent build numbers) across the Servers?

Comment: I don't know that there is any such interaction. I mention the two servers in case there is indeed such a risk, so that someone can point it out to me.

Comment: It's not clear what you're hoping to achieve from switching the servers, so it's hard to guess a solution to the problem. You could clear the build data on the new server using a solution such as https://superuser.com/a/1418896, which should provide a fresh slate of builds and build numbers. If this doesn't suffice, we'd need to see more information on the error, some output, what your requirements are, etc.

Comment: The idea is to move everything (including builds) to a new, faster server. The copy is done (there will be a final rsync at the end), some test builds are running fine, but this one ran into this build number conflict. The error was the following: java.lang.IllegalStateException: /home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/platform set branch name/builds/704 already existed; will not overwite with platform set branch name #704
 at hudson.model.RunMap.put(RunMap.java:187)
 at jenkins.model.lazy.LazyBuildMixIn.newBuild(LazyBuildMixIn.java:178)

Comment: If you are aware of a tried-and-tested copy strategy, by all means share it with me. What I have found is "just copy the .jenkins folder".  Important: the Dev team has not asked for an upgrade, so we're stuck in version 1.609.3.

Comment: Normaly jenkins stores the new build number in the jobs-directory on the master server. If you copy just the .jenkins-directory, the next build number is not included, or am I false?

Comment: At least on our servers, the jobs directory is under .jenkins. Or I'm misunderstanding what you mean.